# mysite link in team site

Tags: mysite

I have two web applications `http:colo01:1000` and `http:colo01:2000` (Mysite configuration is done on the latter).

I want mysites to be accessed from a site collection on the following web application: `http://colo01:1000`

Or is there another way to open MySites from a site collection in `http://colo01:1000` web application?

Thanks,
Ranjith

Comment: I hope I got the edit right :)

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis pretty great that you could even understand what was being conveyed from all that :)

Comment: I just tried to get the wording right, that's it. Still can't understand the question, tho.

Comment: iam created mysite in http:/colo01:2000 . i want access this site from different site collection http:/colo01:1000 . how to set mysite link in http:/colo01:1000  in this site collection.